# how to insert data into arrayList from method like a global variable

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to insert data to an `ArrayList` from the database and I need to use it later, but I can't make it directly. How I can make it then?

```
ngOnInit() { 
var result_array = [];
    this.get_All_Col_data(myfrugalmap,result_array,Marker_array);
    }    

 get_All_Col_data(map,collection_array,markers){
    const myIcon_Col = L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/40/000000/collect.png'
    });
    const myIcon_vente = L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/low-price-euro.png'
    });
    this.CollectionService.getallCollections().subscribe((data: Collection_info[]) =>{
      this.Collection_info = data;
      for(var i =0; i<this.Collection_info.length;i++){
        console.log("name :" + this.Collection_info[i].emailcol);
        console.log("type :" + this.Collection_info[i].type);
        if(this.Collection_info[i].type==='collection'){
             var m = L.marker([Number(this.Collection_info[i].lat_col), Number(this.Collection_info[i].long_col)], {icon: myIcon_Col}).addTo(map);
                 m.bindPopup("Collection pt " + this.Collection_info[i].nom_col);
                 markers.push(m);
                 collection_array.push(this.Collection_info[i]);

            }else{
          var m = L.marker([Number(this.Collection_info[i].lat_col), Number(this.Collection_info[i].long_col)], {icon: myIcon_vente}).addTo(map);
          m.bindPopup("Collection vente " + this.Collection_info[i].nom_col);
          collection_array.push(this.Collection_info[i]);
          markers.push(m);
        }
      }
      console.log(collection_array)
      return collection_array;
     });
```

So I need to fullfill `result_array` with the database info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
export class Test implements OnInit {
    result_arr = [];

    ngOnInit() {
         this.get_All_Col_data(myfrugalmap, Marker_array)
    }

    get_All_Col_data(map, markers){
        const myIcon_Col = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/40/000000/collect.png'
        });
        const myIcon_vente = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/low-price-euro.png'
        });
        this.CollectionService.getallCollections().subscribe((data: Collection_info[])                                 
         =>{
             this.Collection_info = data;
             for(var i =0; i<this.Collection_info.length;i++){
               console.log("name :" + this.Collection_info[i].emailcol);
               console.log("type :" + this.Collection_info[i].type);
               if(this.Collection_info[i].type==='collection'){
                   var m = L.marker([Number(this.Collection_info[i].lat_col), 
                   Number(this.Collection_info[i].long_col)], {icon: myIcon_Col}).addTo(map);
                   m.bindPopup("Collection pt " + this.Collection_info[i].nom_col);
                   markers.push(m);
                  this.result_arr.push(this.Collection_info[i]);
               }else{
                   var m = L.marker([Number(this.Collection_info[i].lat_col), 
                   Number(this.Collection_info[i].long_col)], {icon: myIcon_vente}).addTo(map);
                   m.bindPopup("Collection vente " + this.Collection_info[i].nom_col);
                   this.result_arr.push(this.Collection_info[i]);
                   markers.push(m);
              }
          }
       console.log(this.result_arr)
       });
}
```